`lag()` with `over` and `range between` returns a value if even the previous record is out of range
I want to get the previous value using lag(), over a partition defined with RANGE BETWEEN. I followed an example from the documentation:
WITH orders (custkey, orderdate, totalprice) 
    AS 
    (
    VALUES
    ('cust_1', DATE '2020-10-10', 100),
    ('cust_2', DATE '2020-10-10', 15),
    ('cust_1', DATE '2020-10-15', 200),
    ('cust_1', DATE '2020-10-16', 240),
    ('cust_2', DATE '2020-12-20', 25),
    ('cust_1', DATE '2020-12-25', 140),
    ('cust_2', DATE '2021-01-01', 5)    
)

SELECT *, 
       avg(totalprice) OVER (
                             PARTITION BY custkey
                             ORDER BY orderdate
                             RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS past_month_avg,
    
       lag(totalprice) OVER ( PARTITION BY custkey
                              ORDER BY orderdate
                              RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS previous_total_price_within_last_month
FROM orders

It returns:



custkey
orderdate
totalprice
past_month_avg
previous_total_price_within_last_month




cust_2
2020-10-10
15
15.0
NULL


cust_2
2020-12-20
25
25.0
15


cust_2
2021-01-01
5
15.0
25


cust_1
2020-10-10
100
100.0
NULL


cust_1
2020-10-15
200
150.0
100


cust_1
2020-10-16
240
180.0
200


cust_1
2020-12-25
140
140.0
240



The problem: while the calculation for past_month_avg results as expected, the previous_total_price_within_last_month result is not as expected.

Expected Output
Given that I defined a window that ranges at the last month, I expect that lag() will return null if the "previous" totalprice value is associated with an orderdate value that is out of the 1-month-back window.



custkey
orderdate
totalprice
past_month_avg
previous_total_price_within_last_month




cust_2
2020-10-10
15
15.0
NULL


cust_2
2020-12-20
25
25.0
NULL*


cust_2
2021-01-01
5
15.0
25


cust_1
2020-10-10
100
100.0
NULL


cust_1
2020-10-15
200
150.0
100


cust_1
2020-10-16
240
180.0
200


cust_1
2020-12-25
140
140.0
NULL*



*expected value

Why does cust_2  2021-01-01 have the value 25, shouldn't it be NULL also?

@Charlieface – no. It actually makes sense that the value is 25 and not null because the previous row's orderdate fits the range of 1 month back. That is, DATE('2021-01-01') - INTERVAL '1' MONTH = 2020-12-01, so the previous row (which holds orderdate = 2020-12-20) is within the range (i.e., 2020-12-20 > 2020-12-01).

According to the Trino docs lag should not have Window frame specified. And for latest version specifying frame leads to an error.

Not sure it really makes sense to have a window frame on lag anyway, eg on SQL Server this is also disallowed. Because lead and lag explicltly go by row not ranges or sliding windows. Perhaps you wanted last_value instead?

As written in the comment, lag isn't expected to be supported when using a window frame (e.g., range between).
The following functions are not supported either:
lead, ntile, rank, dense_rank, percent_rank, cume_dist, and row_number.
Please refer to this issue in the Trino project, and to the subsequent pull request.
